# Run DB2 command from a windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, db2

I am trying to run a DB2 command (Import) from a windows batch script.

My approach is..

1. Invoke DB2 command prompt: DB2CMD.exe DB2SETCP.BAT DB2.EXE
2. Connecting to the database: connect to DBNAME USER USERNAME USING PWD
3. Executing DB2 command: IMPORT FROM ...
4. quit

The batch script looks like this..

```
DB2CMD.exe DB2.EXE "connect to dbname USER username USING pwd" "IMPORT FROM D:\File.txt .... INSERT_UPDATE INTO tablename"
quit
```

It is working till the second step and the bat script is exiting without running the third step.

Can anyone guide me on this.. Thanks!

Comment: `CALL DB2SETCP.BAT`

Answer (score 2):

To run Db2 commands in a CMD/BAT file on Microsoft Windows, you need to have a Db2 client installed, and you can begin all of the BAT or CMD files
with the pattern below.  This lets your script open the DB2CMD.EXE if that is not already opened (so you don't need to do it manually).  You also need to have the database catalogued so that you can access the database from the Windows CMD.EXE or DB2CMD.EXE command line. Always verify your commands at the command-line before putting them into a script.

When you get any error, you must *specify* the exact error when asking for help, either by using copy/paste from the db2cmd window or by attaching a screenshot.

Your second step cannot just exit without first showing some error message, although you may need to ensure that the window does not close before you can see that message. There are many reasons for IMPORT to fail, but you have given no information about *which* reason Db2 gave.   If you edit your question to specify the missing error detail, you will get more help on here.

If you run the script on the same hostname where the database is running then you don't need to specify a userid/password and then it connects as the currently logged on User.

If you need to connect to the database with a specific userid (different from the user logged in to Windows) or if you need to connect to a remote database then you must specify a password to the connect command.  You can ask the user to enter a password, for interactive scripts.  If you need to have an unattended script you should avoid hardcoding the password in plain text in the script, or use runas.

The example below shows both a connect to a local database, and a remote database (choose only one of the methods).

```
@if ""%DB2CLP%""=="""" db2cmd /c /i /w ""%0"" %* && goto :EOF

@rem for connecting to a local database as current logged-in Windows account (no password required)
db2 -v connect to dbname
@if errorlevel 1 ( @echo ""FAILED to connect"" && @goto :EOF )


@rem for connecting to a remote database, or connecting with a different account
db2 -v connect to dbname user YOURUSER using THEPASSWORD
@if errorlevel 1 ( @echo ""FAILED to connect"" && @pause ... && @goto :EOF )


db2 -v "IMPORT FROM TO ...  "
@if errorlevel 2 ( @echo "FAILED to export..." && @pause ... && @goto :EOF )
db2 -v connect reset
```